# Xamarin SearchBar not showing the 'X' icon to remove input text in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, xamarin

I am using search bar in one of my application and when the user type something inside the control normally the 'X' icon automatically appear inside the box in iOS, Android and Windows 10 but not in Windows 8.1.

Can you please advice whether is there any workaround to make it apear

Windows 10
[image]

Windows 8.1
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stock Windows SearchBox control doesn't support this. So probably Xamarin has overridden the default control and added the custom button in Windows 10 and not in Windows 8. As Windows 8 doesn't have a bright future it is unlikely that they will ever do that if they haven't by now.

UPDATE: AutoSuggestBox in Windows has a clear button so it could be that Xamarin is using it, but there is no such control in Windows 8.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for your response

Comment: @Ashaar I've also updated the answer right now, though conclusion is the same just it contains more facts.